# iOS Convert AVI to MP4 Format programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one query in my application, for that i want to convert my AVI formatted video to MP4 movie format, so is there any way to do this programatically.

Any code snippet will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `AVAssetExportSession` to convert videos to `.mp4` format, below method convert `.avi` format videos to `.mp4`.

Check the line `exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;` it specify the output format of the video.

Here `inputURL` is an url of video which needs to be converted and `outputURL` will be the final destination of video.

One more thing don't forget to specify `.mp4` extension in `outputURL` video file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

[self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:localUrl outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
{
    if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
        // Video conversation completed
    }          
}];

- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
         handler(exportSession);
     }];
}
```

Comment: In the above code it won't compress the video as you've passed presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough right ? If yes I can use the above code to only trim the video and compression I can do later. Let me know if I'm missing something

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 4.2

An updated version of the accepted answer in **Swift 4.2**.

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("MyVideo.mp4").absoluteString
let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
convertVideoToLowQuailty(withInputURL: inputUrl, outputURL: outputURL, handler: { exportSession in
    if exportSession?.status == .completed {
        // Video conversation completed
    }
})

func convertVideoToLowQuailty(withInputURL inputURL: URL?, outputURL: URL?, handler: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void) {
    if let anURL = outputURL {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: anURL)
    }
    var asset: AVURLAsset? = nil
    if let anURL = inputURL {
        asset = AVURLAsset(url: anURL, options: nil)
    }
    var exportSession: AVAssetExportSession? = nil
    if let anAsset = asset {
        exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: anAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    }
    exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        handler(exportSession)
    })
}
```

Took help from an online conversion [tool](https://swiftify.com/).