# Convert AVI video to MP4 video (for playback on iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I have a video file, which is generated by a third party library, which is recording video from a remote camera.  This API generates a video file in AVI format @ 4fps and, the examples I have, at 352x288px

I've been trying to convert the video for playback in iOS.  I understand that iOS only supports a limited range of video formats and I've been trying to make anything work.

I tried to use the following, which is based on [iOS Convert AVI to MP4 Format programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391124/ios-convert-avi-to-mp4-format-programatically) ...

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  @IBAction func convert(_ sender: Any) {
    makeItSo()
  }

  func makeItSo() {

    guard let inputUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DVR8-4580V, Channel 7", withExtension: "avi") else {
      print("Could not find video source")
      return
    }

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("MyVideo.mp4").absoluteString
    let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    print("OutputURL = \(outputURL)")
    convertVideoToLowQuailty(withInputURL: inputUrl, outputURL: outputURL, handler: { exportSession in
      guard let exportSession = exportSession else {
        print("No export session")
        return
      }
      print("exportSession.status = \(exportSession.status)")
      if exportSession.status == .completed {
        // Video conversation completed
        print("Video converstion completed")
      } else {
        print("Error = \(exportSession.error)")
      }
    })
  }

  func convertVideoToLowQuailty(withInputURL inputURL: URL?, outputURL: URL?, handler: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void) {
    if let anURL = outputURL {
      try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: anURL)
    }
    var asset: AVURLAsset? = nil
    if let anURL = inputURL {
      asset = AVURLAsset(url: anURL, options: nil)
    }
    var exportSession: AVAssetExportSession? = nil
    if let anAsset = asset {
      exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: anAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    }
    exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
      handler(exportSession)
    })
  }

}
```

And several other variants, but they fail.  The above code fails with:

```
Error = Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11822 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x283244bd0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16976 "(null)"}})
```

So I assume that either I'm not providing the correct options/suggestions to the converter or simply AVFoundation doesn't support this type of operation.

Below is the information generated by MediaInfo

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/swhitehead/Downloads/DVR8-4580V, Channel 8.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 361 KiB
Duration                                 : 28s 500ms
Overall bit rate                         : 104 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L2
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=4
Codec ID                                 : H264
Duration                                 : 28s 500ms
Bit rate                                 : 101 Kbps
Width                                    : 352 pixels
Height                                   : 288 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.222
Frame rate                               : 4.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.249
Stream size                              : 351 KiB (97%)
```

## The Question

Is there some way that I can convert this type of video file to a support mp4 format which can played back by iOS?

nb: I appreciate that this potentially a broad question, as a simple solution may not exist, but even some suggestions or hints would be appreciated as it's driving me nuts

Comment: @rmaddy I appreciate that this is not technically a objc based question, but I will accept objc based answers if it helps me find a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use video without “Format settings, GOP : M=1, N=4”.

When I use the video without GOP Format settings, it can be exported successfully.